# AngularJS: Hidden ID not send in the controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

The idea is when I clicked to the account, a modal will pop-up and system menus will be in dropdownlist. My problem is the id for account which I made as hidden type in the form have no value when I send it in the controller.

Here is my form:

```
<form novalidate name="addMenusforuser" ng-submit="addMenuData(addMenusforuser)">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="account_info_id" ng-model="masterlist.account_info_id" value="masterlist.account_info_id">
                <th>
                    System Menus 
                </th>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="masterlist.system_menus_id" ng-options="c.system_menus_id as c.sm_description for c in menus" required></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn">Add</button>
</form>
```

My AngularJS:

```
/**Add Menu to database*/
    $scope.addMenuData = function (form) {
        if (!form.$valid) {
            alert("fill-up everything.");
            return false;
        }
        var formData = [];
        for (index in $scope.masterlist) {
            formData.push({ "name": index, "value": $scope.masterlist[index] });
        }
        $http.post('/Accounts/AddMenusForUser', $.param(formData)).then(function (response) {
            if (form) {
                form.$setPristine();
                form.$setUntouched();
            }
            angular.element("#addMenu").modal("hide");
            $scope.display();
        });
    }
```

And here is my MVC controller where the account_info_id is null:

```
        public ActionResult AddMenusForUser(int system_menus_id = 0, int account_info_id = 0)
        {
            var check = db.System_Menu_Roles.Where(x => x.system_menus_id == system_menus_id && x.account_info_id == account_info_id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (check == null)
            {
                System_Menu_Roles smr = new System_Menu_Roles();
                smr.account_info_id = account_info_id;
                smr.system_menus_id = system_menus_id;
                smr.active_flag = true;
                db.System_Menu_Roles.Add(smr);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Can someone give me advice how will I solve this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you $http.post. Can you log the `$scope.masterlist` and see whether `$scope.masterlist.account_info_id` is there or not. If it's undefined it'll not be sent

Comment: Anyways, I just revise my code and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check You submit function parameter
It should be

```
<form novalidate name="addMenusforuser" ng-submit="addMenuData(masterlist)">
```

And in function

```
$scope.addMenuData = function (form) {
 alert (JSON.stringify(form));
```